# Google chrome opens specific website when ran from launcher

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, .desktop, google

I'm having a problem with my Google Chrome.

When I open it from launcher (I mean bar on the left side) it starts with youtube website, and it starts to play some video. (This happens since my friend send me an youtube link - it plays exact same video)

Anyway when I open good one from launcher menu it starts with normal homepage (two other ones start that video).

[image]

I tried locking good one to launcher, but then it's still opening bad website, when i click it.

I have already tried:

- Reebooting
- `rm *google*` in `~/.local/share/applications/`
- Restoring google chrome's default settings

Should I reinstall it? What am I supposed to do now? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you removed the (extra) launchers from `~/.local/usr/share/applications/`, but it should be `~/.local/share/applications` (without `usr`).

Remove all `google-chrome.desktop` files from `~/.local/share/applications` and all other `.desktop` files that may call `google-chrome`. If you doubt, make the file executable and it will show its icon. Then log out/in.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry for that! It was thinking about `.local/share/applications`. I corrected it

Comment: @Jacajack but still, there really *must* be some left, better do it manually (visually) and make the file executable to see its icon if you have the slightest doubt.

Comment: I have only `chrome.desktop` and `google-chrome-stable.desktop` left there.

Comment: You should remove both and log out/in before using google-chrome again. There is no need to have one locally, since the "good" one is in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Thanks for help! It worked for me! I think i simply didn't remove `chrome.desktop` last time. Now it's ok. But I still wonder how  that bad desktop file got there.... Anyway thanks for help again! :)

Comment: @Jacajack Google chrome is famous for its enthusiasm in creating `.desktop` files :)