# Problem with google chrome icon in launcher (left bar)

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, icons, unity-dash

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and have a problem with launcher (the left bar with bunch of icons).

There is a Google Chrome icon on the launcher. However, when I click it, other google-chrome icon appears at the bottom. When I put the cursor on it, name appears as "Twitter-Google Chrome" where regular icon that is permanently on the launcher appear as "Google Chrome". 
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

typing a command
`google-chrome&`
highlight the Google-chrome (one that's on parmanently on left bar).

opening by the command `google-chrome&` and pressing `Twitter-google chrome` from dash adds extra triangle on the left of `Google-chrome` that is opened by the command.

moving `Twitter-Google chrome` to the upper side of launcher (to place it on permanently), makes it a `?` icon.
Then quit the chrome and clicking the `?` changes the icon to regular `red-yellow-green around the blue` icon and its name to `New tab google chrome`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have some kind of twitter extension or web app or something like that ?

Comment: no I do not. I don't add any add ons on it.

Comment: Try this in a terminal- rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/google-chrome-*.desktop

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate entries in dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516207/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-in-dash)

Comment: You didn't mention  it, but I am pretty sure you also have duplicate appearances in Dash. You simply *must* have duplicate desktop files. Google chrome is famous for that. See the linked post above how to find and remove them. I would start in the directory `~/.local/share/applications`, that's probably where the duplicate(s) are. If you are having doubts on a `.desktop` file, make it executable to have it show its icon.

Comment: take also a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603870/chrome-broken-unity-launcher)

Comment: dash is ok. dash has google chrome when i click it twitter google chrome appears on the sidebar

Comment: All pointing in the same direction. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/598457/google-chrome-opens-specific-website-when-ran-from-launcher/598460#598460

Comment: @JacobVlijm - the issue is probably that the launcher that was clicked issues a sub process, which then gets its own icon - so not a problem with duplicate entries. This happens ALOT with Wine applications

Comment: @Wilf I don't see Wine mentioned in the question :). Also, I really never (ever) ran into a duplicate icon without an additional  `.desktop` file, *unless* the second icon is a generic one. If it simply is an extra "real" icon it really must be a duplicate `.desktop` file. The *file* -name can be confusing though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Though this isn't about Wine (which just gave as a example of where this happens), it is possible for the launcher still to show a icon for things that don't have a launcher file, probably created from the info the program gives the window manager. never mind :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have tried what's on the link. there are bunch of `chrome-abcdefg-Default.desktop` where abcdefg part is a (seems to be a) random 32 alphabets (no numbers).

Comment: `to everyone` I've edited after I've done some experiments with it.

Comment: You can safely remove the local .desktop files, log out /in and lock it again to the launcher. There is no reason to have a local .desktop file on a gloablly installed application unless you want to change ots behyaviour. really, it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Google Chrome from the launcher and adding it back may solve this problem, depending on what is causing the problem. Try this:

- Unlock all Google Chrome from the launcher. (Right-click them to show this option.)
- Add the application to the launcher again by dragging Google Chrome from the dash to the launcher.

Comment: The procedure written as an answer (drag + drop from dash) didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First lookup for the info in ~/.local

```
cd ~/.local
grep -HIrin Twitter-Google
```

this should point you a file where this strange info is
then edit the given file to change the text, and your done